# .desktop is not showing via right click

Tags: .desktop

I created .desktop app and it is stored (/usr/share/applications), (.local/share/applications), but I am unable to open via GUI like..right click on mp4 and open with other application. This .desktop app is not showing on open with other applications categories.

- ****.desktop Content:****

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=djv_player
#Comment=hesk
Exec=sh -x /ASE/app/djv-1.1.0-Linux-64/bin/djv_view.sh    
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/arch.png
Type=Application
Categories=arch;
#Categories=Network;RemoteAccess;
```

any solution for this.

For reference please find attachment[image].

Answer (score 1):

Does the name of the desktop file follow [the appropriate part of the Desktop Entry Specification?](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s02.html#desktop-file-id)

There is no `MimeType=` keyword in the desktop file, so the file is effectively saying that this program is not used with files of any type, like a desktop calculator app for example. So it will not be appropriate to show it in the right-click menu for files of any type.

The fix is to add a `MimeType=` keyword, listing the MIME type(s) of files that this program will be able to open.

You should also add an appropriate field code to the `Exec=` line to tell the system where it should put the filename(s) the program should open. [Here is the appropriate part of the specification.](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html)

- If the program accepts just one pathname, use `%f` where the filename should be placed on the `Exec` command line.
- If the program accepts multiple pathnames, use `%F`.
- If the program can accept URLs, use `%u` or `%U` depending on whether the program can accept just one URL at a time, or multiple URLs, respectively.